# Problem with C header file: Undefined Reference Error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, pointers, header-files

I am currently working on a C programming project and have encountered an issue that I'm struggling to resolve.

The problem:

I am using Visual Studio Code (VS Code) as my code editor. The project consists of the following files:

main.c:

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    List* l = lst_create();
    l = lst_inset(l,10);
    l = lst_inset(l,20);
    l = lst_inset(l,25);
    l = lst_inset(l,30);
    //l = lst_rem(l,10); 
    lst_print(l);

    return 0;
}
```

List.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

struct list
{
    int info;
    List *next;
};

List* lst_create()
{
    return NULL;
}

int lst_empty(List *l)
{
    return (l == NULL);
}

List* lst_inset(List *l, int info)
{
    List* lAux = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));

    lAux -> info = info;
    lAux -> next = l;

    return lAux;
}

List* lst_search(List *l, int info)
{
    List* lAux = l;

    while (lAux != NULL)
    {
        if (lAux -> info == info)
        {
            return lAux;
        }

        lAux = lAux -> next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void lst_print(List *l)
{
    List* lAux = l;

    while (lAux != NULL)
    {
        printf("Info = %d\n", lAux -> info);
        lAux = lAux -> next;
    }
}
```

list.h:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

typedef struct list List;

List* lst_create();

int lst_empty(List *l);

List* lst_inset(List *l, int info);

//List* lst_remove(List *l, int info);

//void lst_free(List *l);

void lst_print(List *l);

List* lst_search(List *l, int info);

#endif
```

I have included "list.h" in "main.c" to use the functions defined in list.c. However, when I attempt to compile the project, I encounter the following linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCzNKTb.o: in function 'main':
/home/user/Codes/C/TestProject/src/main.c:7: undefined reference to 'lst_create'
/home/user/Codes/C/TestProject/src/main.c:8: undefined reference to 'lst_insert'
/home/user/Codes/C/TestProject/src/main.c:9: undefined reference to 'lst_insert'
/home/user/Codes/C/TestProject/src/main.c:10: undefined reference to 'lst_insert'
/home/user/Codes/C/TestProject/src/main.c:11: undefined reference to 'lst_insert'
/home/user/Codes/C/TestProject/src/main.c:13: undefined reference to 'lst_print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have ensured that both main.c and list.c are present in the specified directory. The functions lst_create, lst_insert, and lst_print are declared in list.h and defined in list.c. I have also tested the code in two different C IDEs, but encountered the same "undefined reference" error.I have validated my code by referring to instructional YouTube videos and cross-referenced it with example code. Despite my best efforts, I have not been able to resolve this issue. I even consulted my programming professor, who was unable to identify the problem.

Comment: You need to add `list.c` to the project in your IDE. it's not enough to just have it in the directory

Comment: Yes, it's a linker error. `list.h` was found, otherwise the compiler would have objected.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Is already in the project

Comment: OT: Don't put whitespace around `->`. It's unconventional, distracting and a reasonably likely source of future bugs. Don't cast the return from `malloc()`. Another source of bugs. Use _sizeof object_, not _sizeof type_ with `malloc()`. Less maintenance. Test the return from `malloc()` for success/failure.

Comment: Apparently neither `main.c` nor `list.c` contain function `lst_insert()` reported missing by the linker. They contain `lst_inset()` but that doesn't explain the others. Are you compiling the right files? Did you save the files?

Comment: It appears that list.c is not being compiled - or the compiled objects are not being passed to the linker so the linker cannot find those functions. Could you share the command you use to compile? A trick to ensure a file is compiling is to add  `#error` in the file to see if it throws an error - which it should if that file is compiling.

Comment: @NikolasRian If `list.c` is in the project you must have disabled compiling it (or linking with the resulting object file) somehow.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, hadn't seen this little typo, but it's misspelled in the 3 files, vscode warned of the difference in names when it was fixed

Comment: Aside/Subjective: You should look up a tutorial on how to plainly compile & link C code, manually, in a shell, before relying on your IDE to do it for you. That way you have more accurate knowledge of how this really works, and when things break with your IDE, you at least know what is *supposed* to happen. Avoid YouTube if you enjoy your sanity. Your *professor* not knowing how to solve this is a massive red flag.

Comment: @DannyParker I'm using GCC to compile the files inside VSCode. I even tried to use a command to compile the files together, which generated an executable but when it was executed it just opened and closed the pront quickly

Comment: Then you must have some old garbage lying around. When I compile and run the program, it prints the 4 inserted numbers.

Comment: Also OT: While this is implemented (opaquely) as a LL, its operation is actually a _stack_ (LIFO). Accurately naming things is a **large** part of writing usable code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending the entire afternoon thinking about the problem, I decided to start over from scratch. I chose one of the IDEs that I had previously tested, created a simple test program, and, to my surprise, it worked perfectly. I began copying my code line by line, testing functions as I went along, and everything worked like a charm.

I came to the conclusion that the problem was vscode.

The strange part was that, previously, I had tried to copy and paste the code using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V, but it hadn't worked. Even when I tried copying and pasting again, it failed. For reasons beyond my mortal understanding, the copy-paste operation seemed to be the issue. Nevertheless, the code is now working perfectly.

I'd like to express my gratitude to everyone who responded and tried to help with the problem.

Now my plan is to find a way for VS Code to seamlessly compile all the files together. Compiling via the terminal using `gcc -o program *.c` appears to be a viable approach, so i intend to explore the possibility of creating a tasks.json file or modifying the settings of the C/C++ Compile Run extension that I had been using to simplify the process.

EDIT: I love and hate how things just decide to work out. Now vs code decided that it would compile correctly. I didn't change anything, I didn't update anything, I didn't stop using the extension I was using, it simply worked

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 main categories of errors when working with compiled languages.

- Linker Errors
- Source Errors

Source errors are found when there is invalid syntax inside a specific file.

Linker errors are found when there is invalid links inside a specific file.

The Linker here has reported that it cannot find the specific functions. That is because you did not provide the information to the compiler which in turn, did not provide that information to the linker.

Depending on your specific compiler, you will find some flags which allow you to specify which source files (.c / .cpp) to include in your program. There are usually wildcard specifiers also (*) which allows you to include all source in a given folder.

When developing compiled software, there is another tool which adds further confusion. The IDE. The IDE is simply a tool used to write code with various tricks to make writing code easier. The IDE is NOT a compiler nor a linker. It just knows where to find them in different circumstances. VSCode is great at finding your compiler.